# .value not displaying the proper information in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to capture the user inputted value from an HTML input textbox. If I have a preset, static value assigned it lets me display that value, but that is not what I want. I want the user to input a numeric value and be able to display/modify that value. Thank you for your time.

```
<div class="stats">
    <label>
        Weight<input type="number" id="weight">
    <label>
</div>
<script>
/**
 * @type HTMLInputElement
 */
let weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
console.log(weight/2.205);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script in that script tag executes immediately, once. At page initialization the input is blank and thus there is no value.

Typically you'd have a button that the user clicks after inputting something that runs a function with that logic:

```html
<div class="stats">
    <label>
        Weight<input type="number" id="weight">
    <label>
    <input type="button" value="press" onclick="update()">
</div>
<script>

function update() {
  /**
   * @type HTMLInputElement
   */
  let weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
  console.log(weight/2.205);
}

</script>
```

You may also want the console.log to be executed each time the value is updated, in which case you can use `onchange` attribute directly on the input rather than have a separate button with `onclick`

```html
<div class="stats">
    <label>
        Weight<input type="number" id="weight" onchange="update()">
    <label>
    <input type="button" value="press">
</div>
<script>

function update() {
  /**
   * @type HTMLInputElement
   */
  let weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
  console.log(weight/2.205);
}

</script>
```

Comment: This one must be the accepted answer and especially the second part should be used

Answer (score 2):

This will get the value when a user inputs:

```html
<div class="stats">
    <label>
        Weight<input type="number" onInput="getWeight()" id="weight">
    <label>
</div>
<script>
    function getWeight() {
        let weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
        console.log(weight/2.205);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) that listens to input value changes on the weight input tag.

You will need to use `element.addEventListener` method so that you can run your code every time input event happens.

`element.addEventListener` method accepts:

- event type (this time, input event)
- callback function (this is where your original code goes)
- other options (check MDN for more info)

Inside the script tag, you can register an event listener as follows:

```
let weightInput = document.getElementById('weight');
weightInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
   /* code here runs every time the input event is triggered */
   console.log(weightInput.value/2.205);
});
```